# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax. Getting syntax error in creating procedure

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error in the following procedure near line  `'DECLARE v_cycle_count INT DEFAULT -1;`. If I remove the IF block - `IF pid IS NULL`, error migrates to be `DECLARE v_job_id INT DEFAULT -1;`. If I also remove the code from `-- Look if already running cycle` till next `END IF`, code compiles successfully. I am not able to figure out, what is the error in two blocks.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE startNewCycle(IN pid_in INT, OUT cycleId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE no_initial_job CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
    DECLARE already_running_cycle CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
    DECLARE invalid_input CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';

    IF pid_in IS NULL THEN
         SIGNAL invalid_input SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'process id is null';
    END IF;

    -- Look if already running cycle for this process
    DECLARE v_cycle_count INT DEFAULT -1;
    SELECT count(cycle_id) INTO v_cycle_count FROM cycle_tracking WHERE pid = pid_in AND status = 'RUNNING';
    IF v_cycle_count > 0 THEN
       SIGNAL already_running_cycle SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is already running cycle for this process.';
    END IF;

    -- Look for starting job for the input process id
    DECLARE v_job_id INT DEFAULT -1;
    SELECT job_id INTO v_job_id FROM job WHERE job_id NOT IN (SELECT next_job FROM job WHERE pid = pid_in AND next_job IS NOT NULL) AND pid = pid_in;
    IF v_job_id IS NULL OR v_job_id = -1 THEN
        SET @message_text = CONCAT('There is no initial job for process : ', pid_in);
        SIGNAL no_initial_job SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
    END IF;

    -- start the cycle
    INSERT INTO cycle_tracking(pid, start_date, status) VALUES (pid_in, NOW(), 'RUNNING');
    SET cycleId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    -- signal the initial job
    INSERT INTO job_tracking(cycle_id, pid, job_id, status) 
        VALUES (cycleId, pid_in, v_job_id, 'WAITING_TO_START');  

 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You didn't do any research at all. So -1.

Answer (score 1):

Written clearly in [the documentation for `DECLARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html):

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

So move the declarations to the top of the procedure. And *read the documentation!!*

Answer (score 0):

`DECLARE` goes first. try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE startNewCycle(IN pid_in INT, OUT cycleId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE no_initial_job CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
    DECLARE already_running_cycle CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
    DECLARE invalid_input CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
    -- Look if already running cycle for this process
    DECLARE v_cycle_count INT DEFAULT -1;
    -- Look for starting job for the input process id
    DECLARE v_job_id INT DEFAULT -1;

    IF pid_in IS NULL THEN
         SIGNAL invalid_input SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'process id is null';
    END IF;

    SELECT count(cycle_id) INTO v_cycle_count FROM cycle_tracking WHERE pid = pid_in AND status = 'RUNNING';
    IF v_cycle_count > 0 THEN
       SIGNAL already_running_cycle SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is already running cycle for this process.';
    END IF;

    SELECT job_id INTO v_job_id FROM job WHERE job_id NOT IN (SELECT next_job FROM job WHERE pid = pid_in AND next_job IS NOT NULL) AND pid = pid_in;
    IF v_job_id IS NULL OR v_job_id = -1 THEN
        SET @message_text = CONCAT('There is no initial job for process : ', pid_in);
        SIGNAL no_initial_job SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
    END IF;

    -- start the cycle
    INSERT INTO cycle_tracking(pid, start_date, status) VALUES (pid_in, NOW(), 'RUNNING');
    SET cycleId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    -- signal the initial job
    INSERT INTO job_tracking(cycle_id, pid, job_id, status) 
        VALUES (cycleId, pid_in, v_job_id, 'WAITING_TO_START');  

 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```